# jQuery scope issue, cant call function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function from a jQuery .on but I get this undefined variable when I click the link.

I guess it is a scope issue but I can't work a way to solve it.

```
$.modal.prototype = {
    constructor: $.modal,
    build: function() {

        var next = $('<a>');
        next.addClass('active next-slide');
        next.html ('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
        next.attr("href", "#");
        next.on('click', function() { nextSlide(); });

    },
    nextSlide: function() {
        alert('next');
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextSlide` isn't a standalone function, it is a method of the `$.modal` object. Try this:

```
$.modal.prototype = {
    constructor: $.modal,
    build: function() {
        var _this = this;
        var next = $('<a>');
        next.addClass('active next-slide');
        next.html ('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
        next.attr("href", "#");
        next.on('click', function() { _this.nextSlide(); });

    },
    nextSlide: function() {
        alert('next');
    },
};
```

Comment: sorry I get 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _this'

Comment: Did you add `var _this = this;` at the top of `build`?

Comment: sorry I had not, it works now. Thanks, I will study how this works for future